# VueJS/Webpack - Not exporting sass file to css file

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, vue.js, sass

So I'm facing this problem that in my project I want to use sass as well as Vue but it wont compile.

So far I'm using vue-cli and have to init a normal project(vue init webpack project) and followed the guide here for global https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/configurations/pre-processors.html

And I wand the SCSS file to compile to a CSS and place itself in a folder.

After I've done that nothing happens it runs but without CSS.

Basically I want this -> src/asset/css/style.scss

To compile to this location -> static/css/style.css <- and then be a CSS
file because then I can load it into main.html

### This is the webpack.base.conf file

```
  {
    test: /\.scss$/,
    use: [
      'sass-loader',
      'style-loader',
      'css-loader',
      'postcss-loader',
      {
        loader: 'sass-resources-loader',
        options: {
          resources: path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/assets/css/layout.scss')
        },
      },
    ],
  },
```

### This is the utils file

```
  return {
    css: generateLoaders(),
    postcss: generateLoaders(),
    less: generateLoaders('less'),
    sass: generateLoaders('sass', { indentedSyntax: true }),
    scss: generateLoaders('sass').concat(
      {
        loader: 'sass-resources-loader',
        options: {
          resources: path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/assets/css/layout.scss')
        }
      }
    ),
    stylus: generateLoaders('stylus'),
    styl: generateLoaders('stylus')
  }
}
```

How will I be able to fix this?

Comment: Show us how do you import your `scss` file into the project?

Comment: I dont import it I just want it to compile it into the static folder so I just can include it in index